# How can I use the parameter urlGoogle in the HTML tag <a herf> in Java?

Tags: java, html

How can I use the parameter urlGoogle in the HTML tag  in Java?

```
String urlGoogle = "https://www.google.com";
out.println("<a href='urlGoogle'>google</a>");
```

[image: the image is the error after I run the code]

use the parameter urlGoogle in the HTML tag  in Java

Comment: I suggest that you work through some basic Java tutorials.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html https://www.baeldung.com/string/format  Concatenation, StringBuilder etc.. choose your poison..

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if its what you're looking for but have you tried doing string concatenation? Something like :

```
String urlGoogle = "https://www.google.com";
out.println("<a href='" + urlGoogle + "'>google</a>");
```

String concatenation works almost every time in situations like these :)